# electron webFrame.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld is not a function

Tags: electron

I am trying to use electron's `webFrame.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld` method but I get an error saying its not a function. I am trying to use this in a preload script of a webview.

```
import { webFrame } from 'electron'

webframe.executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld(123 , [{code: 'alert("hello")'}])
```

When I console log the webframe object and check its prototypes then
`executeJavaScriptInIsolatedWorld` is not present there so I understand why I am getting the error. But the electron docs ([here](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-frame#webframeexecutejavascriptinisolatedworldworldid-scripts-usergesture-callback)) mentions that this method is available. I am a little confused by this. Am I using it in the wrong location? Can this not be used inside a webview's preload?

Comment: Which electron version do you use?

Comment: Electron version 1.7.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading docs for 2.0.2 version of electron. 1.7.11 you use https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.7.11/docs/api/web-frame.md doesn't have those interface.

Comment: Oh. I dont know how i missed that. Thanks.